# I want select just 10 image when upload in asp.net. Or When select more than 10 image alert auto without button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want select just 10 image when upload in asp.net. 
Or When I select more than 10 image alert message auto without button..`<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#file').change(function(){
  var input=$(this);
  if(input[0].files.length>10){
    alert('Warning!! Selected files exceeds 10');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" multiple>
```

Comment: use `$('#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>')` instead of `$('#file')`. Note: `FileUpload1` must be the ID of your FileUpload.